# c# Consumir uma API usando POST e header application/x-www-form-urlencoded passando um JSON

Tags: api, aplicação-web

podem me dar uma luz?

Preciso consumir uma API que exige que no seu header tenha um `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
Essa api recebe parametros em json e devolve json.
Usando jquery eu consigo mas preciso criar uma console app para rodar via agendador de tarefas do windows, então preciso fazer usando asp.net web api c# ou coisa do tipo

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'url',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        success: function (data) {
            do it
        },
        error: function (data) {
            do it
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var url = @"https://api-il.traffilog.com/appengine_3/5E1DCD81-5138-4A35-B271-E33D71FFFFD9/1/json";

            var jsonString = @"{
'action': {
    'name': 'user_login',
    'parameters': {
                'login_name': 'user',
        'password': '123'
    }
        }
    }";

            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            content.Headers.Clear();
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ok");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("erro");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Consegui assim mesmo. com o Json em uma string.